# TSQL Converting Characters in XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am generating an XML string in my Code that I send to my stored procedure. Due to the particular data containing an ampersand `&` I have to convert that to something else before sending the XML string as it messes with the XML structure.

I convert any instance of `&` to `~` in the XML string.

Normally, in the past I have re-converted that character once I'm about to add the data to the field and its worked fine.

However, this time around I am inserting a node of XML into a field and that character is contained with in that node.

```
 INSERT INTO TFS_Feedback_New (submitTime, type, reasonID, status, outcome, Details, submitterQID, submitterSupQID, submitterDepartment, submitterGeoLocationDesc, targetQID, targetSupQID, targetDepartment, targetGeoLocationDesc, feedbackOriginal)
SELECT GETUTCDATE(),
       @feedbackType,
       @feedbackReason,
       @status,
       'Pending',
       @xml.query('/data/optional'),
       @submitterQID,
       @SubmitterSupQID,
       @SubmitterDept,
       @SubmitterLoc,
       @TargetQID,
       @TargetSupQID,
       @TargetDept,
       @TargetLoc,
       @feedback
```

As yo u can see, there is a field `@xml.query('/data/optional')`. That is what contains the XML string that has the character I need to replace.

Here is the XML I send to the stored procedure `<optional><fields><department>Dogs ~ Cats</department></fields></optional>`

Before inserting that XML string into the field, I need to convert the `~` to a `&`.

Any ideas?

Comment: what you should be doing is generating correct xml in the first place. `&` should be `&amp;`.

Comment: If `&` isn't allowed then why would `&amp;`  ;)

Comment: because a bare `&` is illegal in xml. it must be encoded as `&amp;`

Comment: List of special characters that will break the `xml` and their replacement `& - &amp;
< - &lt;
> - &gt;
" - &quot;
' - &#39;`

Comment: SBB, not sure if you saw my last edit as I posted it after you accepted (thanks), but I found a super easy way to do the encoding if you are using .NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do proper XML entity encoding. The bare-minimum you need to do is:

- `&` = &amp;
- `<` = &lt;

These are the only two that cause errors when converting to XML:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(XML, '<tag><</tag>');
```

results in:

> Msg 9455, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   XML parsing: line 1, character 7, illegal qualified name character

and

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(XML, '<tag>&</tag>');
```

results in:

> Msg 9421, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   XML parsing: line 1, character 7, illegal name character

**IF** you are doing Attribute-based XML instead of Element-based, then you will also need to translate the double-quote:

- `"` = &quot;

This is due to the possibility of it being placed in an attribute such as:

```
<tag attribute="test &quot; attr">Some stuff here</tag>
```

If you don't have any attributes then translating the double-quote is optional.

You can also do the following, but they won't cause errors if you don't:

- `>` = &gt;
- `'` = &apos;

**NOTE:** Be sure to encode the `&` *first*, and then `<`, and then maybe `"` and possibly `>`. If you don't do `&` first then you will end up double-encoding the other entities that were encoded before it, resulting in something like `&amp;lt;` instead of just `&lt;`.

---

And since you mentioned building the XML in the app code, assuming you are using .NET, you can use the following method to do all of the above for you:

[SecurityElement.Escape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape.aspx)

---

Applying the above to the XML specified in the question, we get the following:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(XML,
       '<optional><fields><department>Dogs &amp; Cats</department></fields></optional>'
              );
```

which converts successfully :).

Answer (score 1):

The `&` character is not allowed in XML strings.  It should be encoded as `&amp;`, for ampersand, or alternatively as `&#038;`, using the [Unicode point for ampersand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML).

See if you can get your client to send `&` as properly encoded `&amp;` XML.  I'd also suggest making your column of type `xml`, so you can rely on it containing syntactically correct XML.